# Type issues with anonymous functions in Purescript

Tags: functional-programming, purescript

I am working through the Purescript By Example tutorial and I am having trouble getting types to line up using a fold left as such:

```
smallestFile' :: [Path] -> Maybe Path
smallestFile' (x : xs) = foldl(\acc i -> smallerFile(acc i) ) Just(x) xs // Error is on this line

smallerFile :: Maybe Path -> Path -> Maybe Path
smallerFile maybeA b = do
  a  <- maybeA
  sa <- size a
  sb <- size b
  if sa > sb then return(b) else return(a)
```

The error I am receiving is on the fold left and is

```
Cannot unify Prim.Function u13116 with Data.Maybe.Maybe
```

I believe that the types line up, but I cannot make heads or tails of this error.

Also, is it possible to clean up the anonymous function syntax so that

```
foldl(\acc i -> smallerFile(acc i) ) Just(x) xs
```

becomes something like:

```
foldl smallerFile Just(x) xs
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PureScript, like Haskell, function application uses whitespace, and associates to the left, which means that `f x y z` parses as `((f x) y) z`. You only need parentheses when terms need to be regrouped. It looks like you're trying to use parentheses for function application.

I suspect what you want to write is

```
foldl (\acc i -> smallerFile acc i) (Just x) xs
```

The argument to `foldl` is a function which takes two arguments `acc` and `i` and returns the application `smallerFile acc i`. This is equivalent to the double application `(smallerFile acc) i`. First we apply the argument `acc`, then the second argument `i`. The precedence rule for function application in the parser makes these equivalent.

Also, `Just x` needs to be parenthesized because what you wrote parses as

```
foldl (\acc i -> smallerFile (acc i)) Just x xs
```

which provides too many arguments to `foldl`.

Once you have the correct version, you can notice that `\acc i -> smallerFile acc i` is equivalent to `\acc -> (\i -> (smallerFile acc) i)`. The inner function applies its argument `i` immediately, so we can simplify this to `\acc -> smallerFile acc`. Applying this simplification a second time, we get just `smallerFile`, so the code becomes:

```
foldl smallerFile (Just x) xs
```

so the only mistake in the end was the incorrect bracketing of `Just x`.